# What does "-r" mean as in the Expect's "expect -r PATTERN" command?

Tags: expect

I have looked in the *Expect* manpage and Googled it, but I have not found what the `-r` for expect is. I saw this option used before like this

```
expect -r "\r\n\r\n"
```

in an `expect` script, but can't figure out what it's for. Does anyone know where I can look to find this answer? Thanks in advance

Comment: are you that it's `-r` but not `\r` or `-re`?

Comment: Please add the full command.

Comment: Yes, it's r. The full command is 'expect -r "somePattern"'

Comment: The one I am seeing is 'expect -r "\r\n\r\n"'

Comment: `-r` is the same as `-regexp`. Within `expect>` prompt you can type `expect --help` and it will complain and give the syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This also confused me a bit when I saw someone was using `expect -regexp PATTERN` because in the man page it only mentions `expect -re PATTERN`. I tried `expect -regexp PATTERN` and it indeed works.

At some time I downloaded Expect's [source code](https://github.com/gashos/expect/blob/1908cefd4d77047481ec37dc20f38fe96721b89e/expect.c#L434) and took a look and found out the reason.

In the source code (see the function `parse_expect_args()` in `expect.c`), the `expect`'s options are actually defined as follows:

```c
static char *flags[] = {
    "-glob", "-regexp", "-exact", "-notransfer", "-nocase",
    "-i", "-indices", "-iread", "-timestamp", "-timeout",
    "-nobrace", "--", (char *)0
};
```

then in the function it calls Tcl's `Tcl_GetIndexFromObj(interp, objPtr, tablePtr, msg, flags, indexPtr)` to parse command options. Accordint to `Tcl_GetIndexFromObj()`'s [manual](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclLib/GetIndex.htm):

> ... a match occurs if `objPtr`'s string value is **identical to one of** the strings in `tablePtr`, **or** if it is a **non-empty unique abbreviation** for exactly one of the strings in `tablePtr` and the `TCL_EXACT` flag was not specified; ...

Here `Expect` calls `Tcl_GetIndexFromObj()` with `flags = 0` (no `TCL_EXACT`) so the documented `-gl`, `-re` and `-ex` in the man page are actually `-glob`, `-regexp` and `-exact` respectively. And since there's only one option `-regexp` starting with `-r` so `-r` just means the same as `-regexp` (and `-re`).

Personally I recommend the documented options still be used to avoid confusing other people.

Comment: Wow! Haha, lots of digging! That's awesome, thanks so much.